# UDK Multiplayer?

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-development-kit

So I've been messing around in UDK and managed to launch a dedicated server console. I can join using my public IP Address although if my friend tries to join using "open HOSTIP" he gets stuck in the loading screen. I have the ports open on my side, does he need to open them too or anything? or am I doing something wrong.

Also I am using this to launch the UDK as a server;
'UDK.exe server DM-Test?game=UTGame.UTTeamGame?listen=true'
If anyone has experience in this any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try defining a port and then have your friend join using "open IP:Port"

```
-port=PortNumber
```

Only the host needs to have the ports open.

You can also host a server with just 'UDK.exe server DM-Test'

```
UDK.exe server DM-Test -port=9000
```